# Save unescaped HTML to string

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string:

```
html = '&lt;div class="blue"&gt; &lt;p&gt;This is a description string'
```

If I do `<%= html.html_safe %>` in my view, it returns the proper string, but not if I do it in the console. If I do:

```
unencoded = html.html_safe
puts unencoded
```

it returns in console

```
&lt;div class="blue"&gt; &lt;p&gt;This is a description string
```

How do I decode the string so I can perform operations on the tags using Nokogiri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me in the end was to gsub the < and > symbols in my html.

like so

```
    html.gsub! '&lt;','<'
    html.gsub! '&gt;','>'
```

after doing that to my html variable I was able to parse it with Nokogiri

Answer (score 2):

You can unescape all of the HTML entities with `CGI.unescapeHTML`:

```
html = '&lt;div class="blue"&gt; &lt;p&gt;This is a description string'
CGI.unescapeHTML(html)
# => "<div class=\"blue\"> <p>This is a description string"
```